# Is it possible to create a storage provider for user data on a Windows Phone device?

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-data

The [`Microsoft.Phone.UserData.StorageKind` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.storagekind%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) *implies* that "other" storage locations can exist for storing use data, such as appointments and contact details. Is it possible to create a provider that can be installed as part of an App (such that the data becomes aggregated in a similar manner to that from Twitter, LinkedIn, Facebook, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to extend the platform by creating providers.

In the enumeration you refer to `Other` would include Twitter and LinkedIn (and Google or a mail provider, etc.).

Comment: How do these other services do it then?

Comment: @RowlandShaw they are built in by Microsoft as part of the platform